# Scale images with a maximum limit for their number of pixels

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I have lots of images in different shapes and sizes and I want to scale them in a way that the number of their pixels be smaller than a maximum. I also want to keep the aspect ratios of the original images. I came up with this:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("example.jpg")
max_pix = 65536

r = img.size[0] / img.size[1]
if r > 1:
    r **= -1  # because I don't know if the height is bigger or the width

n = int(sqrt(max_pix/r))
img.thumbnail((n, n))

img.save("example.jpg")
```

At most, `r` will be 1, so the number of pixels (n * n) will be equal to `max_pix`. Otherwise it will be smaller than that.
Is there a better way to do this? I'm gonna do this a lot of times, so I'm looking for the most efficient way.

Comment: I'm intrigued. What would be the reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: @Mark I want to use these images as inputs in a neural network. I'm resizing all images because the number of inputs (pixels) is a fixed value; and by padding, I'll be able to fit them all in input neurons.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Rather than worry about the efficiency of the `if` statement, you are likely to get much better performance by multiprocessing to do many images at once on a multi-core CPU if you have thousands of images to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with the behaviour of your algorithm, I doubt the efficiency of those three or four lines of Python matters at all. Even though doing maths in Python is slow, it will be at least an order of magnitude (or likely more) faster than scaling 64K+ pixels anyway.

If you're looking for a speed bump, you could check if there are faster alternatives to Pillow, such as [Pillow-SIMD](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow-SIMD/), and benchmark them for your use case.

Comment: thank u, I was just wondering if there are functions to do the math or maybe a way to get rid of the `if`.